# How to upload an image to server in android using kotlin in multipartbody

Tags: android, image, kotlin, post, multipartform-data

i am trying to send an image from the users storage to the server,but the problem is the image is not upoloading,showing as null.
i have put the viewmodel below.I get the uri from the fragment screen and sent it to the viewmodel then get the real path and create it to a file.resize the aspect ration of the image to 1:1 as it is required and then convert it into multipartbody.part form but the image is not receiving in the server side.I dont know what the problem is.the other data is receiving at the server

```
class AddProductViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    var _apiLiveData = MutableLiveData<Resource<AddProductResponse>>()
    val apiLiveData: MutableLiveData<Resource<AddProductResponse>> get() = _apiLiveData

    fun addProduct(
        productName: String,
        productType: String,
        price: String,
        tax: String,
        imageUri: Uri? = null
    ) {

        _apiLiveData.postValue(Resource.Loading)


        viewModelScope.launch {
            val imagePart = if (imageUri != null) {
                val imageFilePath = context.getRealPathFromURI(imageUri)

                fileToMultipartBodyPart(imageFilePath!!)
            } else {
                null
            }

//            val requestFile = RequestBody.create("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull(), file)
//        val imagePart =  MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("files", file.name, requestFile)


            val apiInterface =
                RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiInterface::class.java)
            apiInterface.addProductData(
                toRequestBody(productName),
                toRequestBody(productType),
                toRequestBody(price),
                toRequestBody(tax),
                listOfNotNull(imagePart)
            )
                .enqueue(
                    object : Callback<AddProductResponse> {
                        override fun onResponse(
                            call: Call<AddProductResponse>,
                            response: Response<AddProductResponse>
                        ) {
                            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                                if (response.body()!!.message == "Product added Successfully!") {
                                    _apiLiveData.postValue(Resource.Success(response.body()!!))

                                } else
                                    _apiLiveData.postValue(
                                        Resource.Failure(
                                            false,
                                            0,
                                            response.body()!!.message
                                        )
                                    )
                            }
                        }

                        override fun onFailure(call: Call<AddProductResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                            _apiLiveData.postValue(Resource.Failure(true, 0, "Network Error"))

                        }

                    }
                )
        }

    }

    private val context: Context
        get() = getApplication<Application>()

    private fun toRequestBody(value: String): RequestBody {
        return RequestBody.create("text/plain".toMediaTypeOrNull(), value)
    }

    private fun Context.getRealPathFromURI(uri: Uri): String? {
        val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
        val cursor: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null)
        return cursor?.use {
            val columnIndex = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
            it.moveToFirst()
            it.getString(columnIndex)
        }
    }

    private fun fileToMultipartBodyPart(filePath: String): MultipartBody.Part {
    //        val file = File(filePath)
    //        val requestFile = RequestBody.create("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull(), file)
    //        return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("files", file.name, requestFile)
        // Load the original image file
        val originalFile = File(filePath)

        // Calculate the desired width and height for the 1:1 aspect ratio
        val desiredWidth = 500 // Set your desired width
        val desiredHeight = 500 // Set your desired height

        // Resize the image
        val resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(originalFile.absolutePath),
            desiredWidth,
            desiredHeight,
            false
        )

        // Save the resized bitmap to a new file
        val resizedFile = File(context.cacheDir, "resized_image.jpg")
        val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(resizedFile)
        resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fileOutputStream)
        fileOutputStream.close()

        // Create a RequestBody from the resized file
        val requestFile = RequestBody.create("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull(), resizedFile)

        // Create MultipartBody.Part
        return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("files", resizedFile.name, requestFile)
    }
}

interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("get")
    fun getProductData(): Call<List<ProductResponse>>

    @Multipart
    @POST("add")
    fun addProductData(
        @Part("product_name") productName: RequestBody,
        @Part("product_type") productType: RequestBody,
        @Part("price") price: RequestBody,
        @Part("tax") tax: RequestBody,
        @Part files: List<MultipartBody.Part>? = null
    ): Call<AddProductResponse>

}
These are bits of code from the fragment
uploadImage.setOnClickListener {
            pickImageFromGallery()
        }




        submitBtn.setOnClickListener {
            if (editTextProductName.text!!.isEmpty() || editTextProductTax.text!!.isEmpty()
                || editTextProductSellingPrice.text!!.isEmpty()
            ) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "One or more fields empty!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else {
                if (selectedImageUri != null) {
                    MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM).apply {
                        addFormDataPart("product_name", editTextProductName.text.toString())
                        addFormDataPart("product_type", productTypeSpinner.selectedItem.toString())
                        addFormDataPart("price", editTextProductSellingPrice.text.toString())
                        addFormDataPart("tax", editTextProductTax.text.toString())


                    }.build()


                    viewModel.addProduct(
                        editTextProductName.text.toString(),
                        productTypeSpinner.selectedItem.toString(),
                        editTextProductSellingPrice.text.toString(),
                        editTextProductTax.text.toString(),
                        selectedImageUri// Pass the MultipartBody parts
                    )

 private fun pickImageFromGallery() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            selectedImageUri = data.data

            Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), selectedImageUri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```

Comment: `then get the real path ` That is pretty wrong. Just use the uri to upload the selected file.

Comment: could you help me.Im stuck on this for quite some time.Can you provide  moew details

Comment: @blackapps could you provide more details on this and help me.I'm new to android

Comment: Well tell where you wanted to use that path for. Realise that i did not look at your code yet.

Comment: @blackapps i have gotten the uri and used it to create the file.i have tried to create a multipart form request and post the image along with some values.the values are being uploaded but the image is not.

Comment: `i have gotten the uri and used it to create the file.` You got an uri of an existing file. So there was nothing to create.

Comment: Further i asked where you used the path for and you still did not tell.

Comment: I use "Ktor" for that. All works well https://ktor.io/docs/request.html